# split a large file with mac in command line by context

Tags: macos, command-line

I have been trying to split a large file (some GB) into pieces, I need to chunk the file by linenumber (say, containings about 1M lines each).

How could I do?
csplit does not work, goes out of memory.
Below, an example of the content:

```
690451  World_War_II    Allies_of_World_War_II
690451  World_War_II    Axis_powers_of_World_War_II
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command line tool `split` with the `-l` (lines) option.

```
split -l 1000000
```

Comment: Ahhhh Thank you so much Daniel, it was so simple!!! Ich danke lhenen :D

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to click the checkmark next to my answer to mark this question answered.

Comment: Thanks. Although I have to add to my answer, it ignores any context. But except for the title, you didn't mention that again, so I wasn't sure how to interpret that...